# Allow user to input Strings and Integers

Tags: java

What would the code to be to allow a user to input text and integers. I am creating a GPA Calculator and the program asks for what course the user is taking, which then is stored as a variable. For example. "Calculus 12." I was able to fix this issue by making the string and the integer two separate variables. How would I make it so that the user can type in "Calculus 12" and have the entire thing be stored as a variable with no issues?

```
    System.out.println("For the next set of questions, please answer without typing in a number. ");
    System.out.println("For example, 'Pre-Calculus'. ");

    System.out.print( name + ", What is the 1st course are you taking? ");
    course1 = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("What level is it? Type in a value: ");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: `String newVariable = course1 + " " + num1;`?

Comment: [`keyboard.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())?

Comment: read in the whole line as a single string (see @Johnny's comment), then use string.split to separate out the various fields:  `String[] splits = input.split("\\s+");`  You can then, if you need the second and/or following fields to be numbers, you can then parse them into numbers with `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Use  keyboard.nextLine() instead of  keyboard.next().